# Disable Print Screen Button in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, disabled-control

I want to Disable Print Screen Button in my Wordpress(Woocommerce) Website. Although i know that there are many tools that can still capture the screen but if i assume that no one knows about any kind of tool to capture and no one knows to disable JS,in that case i just need to simply disable that button for all the browsers.

Comment: If you don't want anyone capturing what you print on the screen, then don't print anything on the screen.

Comment: If you talk about the print screen button in keyboard, it's a system-level thing not a browser-level thing. Your code doesn't have access to system resources, and so it's impossible to disable the behavior.

Comment: If even if *could* do this in JS, remember JS can be disabled.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer i know that JS can be Disabled but how can i do this in JS and where can i write this JS function in WP?

Answer (score 0):

Try [WP Content Copy Protection plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-content-copy-protection/)

**Features:**

1. iFrame Protection
2. Disables right click function on mouse
3. Disables image drag and drop function
4. Disables 'Hold to Copy' function on most mobile devices
5. Displays a client-side error message when Javascript is disabled
6. Serves blank pages when JS is turned off in user browser (user is
   forced to enable JS)
7. **Disables keyboard copy commands (CTRL A, C, X, U, P)
   copy/paste/print/view source**

I think no.7 is what you want